# Random walk generate OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: python, type-conversion

I edited a chuck of random walk code from [this link](https://github.com/sdrap/sdrap.github.io/blob/538dba47180ce5b64b03c01ffe79eb70bed2790d/downloads/WS2015/StochProcess/Materials/Random%20Walk.ipynb) (ps: the orginal one works):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

days = 100 # time horizon
random.seed(2022)

def random_walk(startprice):
    price = np.zeros(days)
    
    x = np.round(np.random.uniform(0, 10, days))
    y = np.round(np.random.uniform(0, 10, days))
    
    price[0] = startprice
    for i in range(1, days):
        price[i] = (1 + 0.8*x[i] + 1.5*y[i])*price[i-1]
        # print(price[i])
    return price

fig, axn = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
for run in range(10):
    axn.plot(random_walk(10), label='time', linewidth='2')
```

But my edited version throw out an error: `OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer`, does someone could help to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't get any error running your code

Comment: It seems not stable, please try to set `days = 1300` and rerun the code to see if you get errors?

Comment: The problem seems caused by `random.seed(2022)`, when I changed it to `np.random.seed(2022)`, no errors any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `x[i]` *can* be as large as 10, and so can `y[1]`, so

```
 (1 + 0.8*x[i] + 1.5*y[i])*price[i-1]
```

can be as large as `(1 + 0.8*10 + 1.5*10)*price[i-1]` = `24.0 * price[i-1]`.

You only need a few hundred of those chained to overflow to infinity:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.nextafter(math.inf, 0)
1.7976931348623157e+308
>>> math.log(_, 24)
223.3387949931843
```

Of course they won't all be 10, but it doesn't matter all that much: exponential growth quickly explodes regardless. If, e.g., they were all 5 instead:

```
>>> math.log(1.7976931348623157e+308, 5)
441.0127954671545
```

The question is more why you *don't* expect it to overflow to infinity?

Note that the code you started from did *not* multiply on each step. It *added* a "random shock" instead. That's far better behaved.